# Python Error Interfacing with excel Writing a formula to a range of cells

Tags: python, openpyxl, unicode-escapes

I am getting an error associated with this code of unicodeescape codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3; truncated \uxxxxxxxxxxxxxx escape. I'm a new "programmer." Please help. I appreciate it very much!

```
import os
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.abspath('C:/Users/S/Desktop/Database.xlsx'))
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Search_Result 2')
for i in range(11503,16897):
    cellref=sheet.cell(row=i,column=4)
    cellref.value="CIQRANGEA(B"&i&",'IQ_COMPANY_ID_QUICK_MATCH',1,1,,,,,'QUICK MATCH COMPANY ID'")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: That can't be your code as that raises a syntax error. Please copy--paste your actual code but try to provide a minimal-reproducible example.

Comment: What do you mean - that is my entire code. What am i doing wrong? What am i missing here?

Comment: For one, you're missing a colon (:) at the end of the `for i in ...` file. Then the quotes and the parentheses are messed up in the `cellref.value=...` line. Then the ampersands (`&`) will raise additional errors. So do not claim that the above is your actual code which raises a unicodeescape error.

Comment: So the formula that is in excel needs quotes so that's what I was doing. The Ampersand is so that the i variable can be changed each time. Is this not how you do it on python? I know AppleScript works this way. Please help. Where does the colon go. All I am trying to do is write a loop value for each row with the excel formula CIQRange . . . Im just trying to write to the cells. Like using copy down but excel seems to screw it up because each time the server that excel is pulling from can't get all the 5000+ requests so its going very slowly. So trying to write a script that automates the pull

Comment: I've revised it to take into account a few typos. Does this make more sense now? I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. First step would be to comment out `cellref.value` and just make the code loop through each row. (I'm not sure how it's working, it should NOT be possible as you're missing a colon `:` (on the for each loop). To keep the code simple, why not change `range(11503,16897)` to say `range(1, 5)`? Also how is `time.sleep(2)` relevant for the question?

Comment: @Justin This is likely the code that reproduces the error reported since the error is on the second line. The OP needs a raw string, doubled backslashes, or forward slashes for the path. There are clearly lots more errors and the OP should read a good Python tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added the colon. What do you mean comment out cellref.value? I am just trying to write to the cell using python an excel formula, that is: "=CapIQRange(...)." I am using value as a way to write to the cell in excel. Is that not right? As for the time.sleep. I think you are right that it does not have a place here, but I am trying to delay the hit to the CapIQRange server via the excel formula because that get overloaded when I do it in excel.

Comment: Also changed the file path - Is this more correct now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user7875084 - always try and fix one problem at a time. Can you loop through the code yet (to reach breakpoint on `time.sleep(2)`)? If so, then you can update the question with the data or formula you'll like to add in the cell (with an example)?

Comment: Change the file path to use / instead of \ to avoid potential problems with \ escape characters

Comment: Yes that was the solution: to change the slashes. Thank you. Now my problem seems to be in the CIQRange part with the i variable.

Comment: what would CIQRANGEA look like as plain text?

Comment: It is an excel formula in excel that looks like this: =CIQRANGEA(A1,"IQ_COMPANY_ID_QUICK_MATCH",1,1,,,,,"QUICK MATCH COMPANY ID"). I am trying to loop the rows by changing the 1 in A1 - but for me its B1 B2 etc.

Comment: I'm guessing: `cellref.value=f"=CIQRANGEA(A{i},'IQ_COMPANY_ID_QUICK_MATCH',1,1,,,,,'QUICK MATCH COMPANY ID')"`

Comment: I'm now not getting any errors. Thank you. But it also doesn't seem like excel is doing anything different. So there's no effect after running the code? It says that wb.getsheet name line is deprecated - perhaps this is it?

Comment: have you added a break point & seen what code lines of code is running?

Comment: How do you do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode error is due to the `\` character in the file path, which initiates an escape sequence. To fix this issue, add an r before the string to use a raw string, like this:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\S\Desktop\Database.xlsx"))
```